# vue.js reference div id on v-on:click

Tags: onclick, vue.js

Using `v-on:click` I'd like to set a variable with the id of the div in Vue.JS - how do I reference this?

```
<div id="foo" v-on:click="select">...</div>

<script>
    new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {
        },
        methods: {
            select: function(){
                divID = this.id // ??
                alert(divID)
            }
        }
    })
</script>
```

Answer (score 86, accepted):

You can extend your event handler with the event object `$event`. That should fit your needs:

```html
<div id="foo" v-on:click="select($event)">...</div>
```

The event is passed on in javascript:

```js
export default {
    methods: {
        select: function(event) {
            targetId = event.currentTarget.id;
            console.log(targetId); // returns 'foo'
        }
    }
}
```

As mentioned in the comments, `$event` is not strictly necessary, when using it as the only parameter. It's a nice reminder that this property is passed on, when writing it explicitly.

However, nobody will stop you from writing the short notation:

```html
<div id="foo" @click="select">...</div>
```

Beware that the method will not receive the `$event` object when you add another parameter. You need to explicitly add it at the position you will handle it in the listener. Any parameter order will work:

```html
<div id="foo" @click="select(bar, $event)">...</div>
```

To find more options of the `v-on` directive, you can look through the corresponding entry in the vue documentation:

**[Vue API Documentation - v-on](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-on)**

Comment: Thanks. it would seem you don't need to include '($event)' in the v-on statement and it still works.

Comment: 'event.currentTarget' isn't mentioned in the VueJS docs - where is this information from? Asking so I can find other functions!

Comment: While this is correct, I would advise against it. The reason behind this (besides making it explicit): You can pass any number of parameters and the behaviour would break for other signatures like: `select(number, event)`

Comment: The event object is a web standard: [MDN - Event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event).
If this answer helped you, consider accepting it :)

Comment: How would you use it with parameters included?

Comment: Just add the `$event` wherever you want it: `@click="select(bar, $event)"` or `@click="select($event, bar)"`

Answer (score 2):

Inspired by @nirazul's answer, **to retrieve data attributes**:

**HTML:**

```
<ul>
    <li
            v-for="style in styles"
            :key="style.id"
            @click="doFilter"
            data-filter-section="data_1"
            :data-filter-size="style.size"
    >
        {{style.name}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

**JS:**

```
export default {
    methods: {
        doFilter(e) {
            let curTarget = e.currentTarget;
            let curTargetData = curTarget.dataset;
            if (curTargetData) {
                console.log("Section: " + curTargetData.filterSection);
                console.log("Size: " + curTargetData.filterSize);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why making the detour if you can just do `@click="doFilter(style)"` directly?

Comment: @nirazul, I altered the example to demonstrate how I passed data attributes. In my real example, many additional arguments (which does not only include style) are there. I'll edit the answer to make it more obvious.

Answer (score -2):

Just to highlight another option than the selected answer for the same question, I have a delete button on a record and want to perform an action with the record's unique id (a number). I could do the selected answer as before:

```html
<button :id="record.id" @click="del">&times;</button>
```

This leaves the unfortunate reality that my `del` function needs to pull the id attribute out of the javascript event, which is more about the API (the DOM) than my domain (my app). Also using a number as an element `id` isn't ideal and could cause a conflict if I do it more than once in a view. So here's something that's just as clear and avoids any future confusion:

```html
<button @click="()=>del(record.id)">&times;</button>
```

```js
methods: {
  del(id) {
    fetch(`/api/item/${id}`, {method:"DELETE"})
  }
}
```

You see, now my `del` function takes the record id instead of an event, simplifying things.

---

<strike>Note that if you do this wrong, you will invoke your delete function immediately, which is not what you want. Don't do this:~~</strike>

```html
<button @click="del(record.id)">&times;</button>
```

If you end up doing that, Vue will call the `del` function every time this html fragment is rendered. Using the anonymous function `()=>del(record.id)` will return a function that's ready to be executed when the click event happens.

Actually @nirazul proved this is fine. Not sure what my issue was.

Comment: This is simply not true, functions in event arguments won't be immediately executed when the template renders: https://codepen.io/nirazul/pen/pYJbKd?editors=1010